# How do D flip-flops (dff) start up in Quartus?

Tags: flipflop, quartus

If I connect Q0 of one dff to its D0, its Q0 stays 0. But if I take another dff and connect its Q1 with Q0 of the first dff through OR to his D1, its Q1 *stays 1*.

[image: Scheme of the circuit described above[1]]

I understood that all registers are initialized to zero on FPGA power-up. But even if so, when I compile the design and run it on the FPGA, LED0 is off, ***while LED1 is on!***

[EDIT] If k0 is 1 at any point, how come that it doesn't stay 1, given that it is directly connected to D?

What is actually happening here?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Your question sounds very confused. You can't run a program on your FPGA, it hasn't got a microprocessor in it. You mean implement your logic circuit. Meanwhile, how does Quartus 'power up'? It's a logic synthesis program. I think you've got a lot of confusion over the fundamentals and that needs some research and learning well beyond what this site does. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: I meant FPGA power up, not Quartus power up, and 'design' instead of 'program', if it makes any difference. [I edited the answer accordingly]. Still, I think the main question was pretty clear nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

> What is actually happening here?

Your flip flops need a clock (minimum) and a reset (if you want them to be reset to a known state (you do). Like this:

[image]
Source: http://hep-outreach.uchicago.edu/samples/3bit_counter/

If you look at a d flip flop truth table a state transition *requires a clock* otherwise it will stay in the same state.

[image]
Source: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/4013-D-flip-flop-circuit.php

Comment: When I implemented proper reset circuit, my design did work. (It is a controller unit actually, and not all dffs had to be 0). However, while debugging, at one point I tried these two circuits as described and couldn't comprehend their behavior. I thought that maybe I could learn something about how Quartus/FPGA operates by understanding this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that a clock edge...most likely the first one...is occurring before the OR gate has settled.  You could test for this by delaying the clock a few cycles, or possibly by inverting it.  Once it's set, of course, it will remain set indefinitely.

Comment: One thing I tried is connecting this k0 to S of SR ff (and connecting 0 to R). When a LED is connected to Q, *it is on*. Meaning that it is not dependent on the OR gate, and that k0 is in fact 1 at **some** point.

Comment: This would be consistent with the first clock edge appearing at about the time the unit comes out of its initialization phase.  k0 would be 0 by the time the first clock edge hits, but that 0 may be delayed enough propagating through the OR that k1 is latched high.

Answer (score 0):

> "I understood that all registers are initialized to zero on FPGA power-up"

Where is this guaranteed? It's normal practice to construct a reset circuit driven by a reset pin to ensure things initialise to a specific state. This is what the PRN inputs are for.

It's also normal practice to make sure that all unused inputs are tied to either 0 or 1 as appropriate. PRN and CLRN should be tied to 1 if you're not using them.

Lastly you've not used a clock. DFFs do not change their output until they receive a clock edge. Or an *asynchronous* reset signal. I'm not sure whether those DFFs have synchronous or asynchronous reset inputs.

Comment: I have used the clock, of course, it is named 'clk'. [I have omitted showing the input pin tied to a clock for simplicity]. From what I have found online, registers are indeed initialized to 0, while PRN and CLRN are asynchronous. (They are also automatically tied to VCC if left unused). Still, I do not see how this behavior is possible in any circumstance.